# Adding chat through websocket, to an existing PHP web app

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, chat, web-chat

I have an existing web application on the standard PHP/Apache platform. Now, what I want is to add chat functionality, and I want it to be real-time over a websocket, and to that extend I've studied socket.io on nodejs a little bit. So in addition to Apache running the big PHP app, I would have nodejs with socket.io running chat.

But what I don't really understand, is how would I recognise my users in the code for nodejs chat? For one, Apache and nodejs won't be able to run on the same port, meaning I'll run chat on port `8080` for example, in which case I lose the user's cookies, which then means I now have to ask them to log in once more on this nodejs-powered port if they want to use chat? Seems ridiculous, but I don't know which way to go about it.

I cannot port my entire code onto nodejs, of course. So ideally I would want Apache and nodejs to coexist. Or I am just completely misunderstanding how chat is supposed to work in web apps.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: You can run a WebSocket server in PHP, assuming you can configure your server appropriately.

Comment: If you switch over to Nginx you can do it on the same port with the same url for example 'exampe.com/chat` points to the nodejs system and everything else points to the PHP system.

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316681/adding-chat-through-websocket-to-an-existing-php-web-app/41317209#41317209) below help you? Any comments?

Comment: @rsp I think that's probably the solution I'll end up going with, if everything goes fine setting it up. I just didn't catch a chance to play with it in the meantime. I'll accept your answer as soon as I try it if I won't have any additional issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your Apache with PHP on e.g. port 3001 and your Node app on port 3002, and have nginx configured as a reverse proxy to make them both available on port 80, for example your PHP app in the root `/` directory and your Node app in the `/chat` directory, with nginx config like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location /chat {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

With SSL it would be slightly more complicated but not that much:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=3600";
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /.../chained2.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /.../domain.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /chat {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

}
```

Your PHP and Node apps could even run on different servers - just use their addresses in the nginx config.

See this answer and its comments for more details:

- [reverse proxy using ngix and ssl implementation on express failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913193/reverse-proxy-using-ngix-and-ssl-implementation-on-express-failed/40913370#40913370)

Comment: how can I configure for two process running on two machines with the gunicorn ?  do we need to enable nginx for those services with the private ip and call inside main nginx ?